# Как добавлять класс элементу по условию?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ряд блоков на странице с высотой от 20px до 40px.
Я создал условие при котором если у блока высота больше 20px, добавлялся класс:

```
$(".des-info__wrapper h2").each(function() {
    var $minHeight = 20;
    if ( $(this).height() > $minHeight) {
        $( ".des-info__wrapper h2" ).addClass( "_fix" );
    }
});
```

Но он добавляет этот класс абсолютно ко всем элементам в итоге, а не только к тем, у кого эта высота больше 20px.
Как это исправить? Надо что-бы все блоки слушались и только у тех, где высота больше 20px добавлялся класс _fix.

Comment: "высота **больше** 20px" - `if ( $(this).height() < $minHeight)` ??

Comment: Это опечатка, знак в другую сторону верно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте так

```
$( this ).addClass( "_fix" );
```

А не

```
 $( ".des-info__wrapper h2" ).addClass( "_fix" );
```

Вы проверяете блок и добавляете во все этот класс. Тогда если хоть один попадет по условию применит ко всем

Comment: Спасибо за решение!